# Multiple updates in execute immediate

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a couple of update statements that I have to execute dynamically . I am executing both these update statements using execute immediate. However, I get the following error when I do so :

```
ORA-00911: invalid character
ORA-06512: at line 7
00911. 00000 -  "invalid character"
*Cause:    identifiers may not start with any ASCII character other than ..
```

Is there a limitation that one cannot execute more than 1 update statement in Execute immediate ?

Edit: With example:

```
begin 
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE tt_TGT_TABLE SET PK_1 = ''Demand10'' where ROW_ID = 3923866 ; UPDATE tt_TGT_TABLE SET PK_1 = ''Demand11'' where ROW_ID = 3923868'; 
end;
```

Comment: Why do you need `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` for this? Unless you don't know the columns/tables you need to update at compile time, static PL/SQL would be the much better choice.

Comment: yeah i understand . i have only constructed an example to explain the issue i am facing. in this particular example the value of PK_1 is a variable . hence the use of execute immediate.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot simply concatenate multiple statements within an `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` call - you'll either have to use several calls:

```
begin 
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE tt_TGT_TABLE SET PK_1 = ''Demand10'' where ROW_ID = 3923866';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE tt_TGT_TABLE SET PK_1 = ''Demand11'' where ROW_ID = 3923868'; 
end;
```

or feed an anonymous PL/SQL block into `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`:

```
begin 
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '
    begin
      UPDATE tt_TGT_TABLE SET PK_1 = ''Demand10'' where ROW_ID = 3923866;
      UPDATE tt_TGT_TABLE SET PK_1 = ''Demand11'' where ROW_ID = 3923868;
    end;';   
end;
```

Comment: yeah  ,  i went for the first approach . but thought maybe i am missing something. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If update statements are static then the way Frank suggested is very good. But if update statements are dynamic then you can follow below approach, where split the entire statement based on ';'. then do execute immendiate on each statement seperately.

```
BEGIN
V_INIPOSITION :=1;
V_SQL:= 'UPDATE tt_TGT_TABLE SET PK_1 = ''Demand10'' where ROW_ID = 3923866;UPDATE tt_TGT_TABLE SET PK_1 = ''Demand11'' where ROW_ID = 3923868';
SELECT LENGTH(V_SQL) INTO V_LEN FROM DUAL;
SELECT INSTR(V_SQL,';',v_iniposition,1) INTO V_FINALPOSITION FROM DUAL;
SELECT SUBSTR (V_SQL,V_INIPOSITION, v_finalposition-1) INTO V_QUERY FROM DUAL;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (V_QUERY);
SELECT SUBSTR (V_SQL,v_finalposition+1, V_LEN) INTO V_QUERY FROM DUAL;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (V_QUERY);
End;
```

If number of SQL statemets are also not fixed then that can be achived using this method and looping.

Comment: What about `;` in comments and char constants?